# Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value and notification long delay

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification, google-cloud-functions

i am getting firebase returned undefined,expected promise or value whenever the code is executed, in addition in it taking a very long time that the notification is sent

```
'use-strict'
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.channelNotification = functions.database.ref('/ChannelMessages/{channelid}/{messageid}').onCreate(event => {
    const channelid1 = event.params.channelid;
    admin.database().ref('/Channels/' + channelid1 + '/Users').on("child_added", function (snapshot, childkey) {
         admin.database().ref('/Channels/' + channelid1 + '/Users/' + childkey + '/deviceToken').once('value',function(token){
            admin.database().ref('/Channels/' + channelid1 + '/name').once('value',function(name){
                admin.database().ref('/Channels/' + channelid1 + '/profilePic').once('value',function(pp){
                    const payload = {
                        data: {
                            "title" : name,
                            "body"  : event.data.val().content,
                            "icon"  : pp,
                            "id"  : channelid1,
                            "type"  : "channel"
                        }
                    };  
                    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload).then(response => {
                        console.log('nice feature');
                    });
                });
            });
         });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a promise from the function that resolves when all the asynchronous work is complete.  Right now, you're returning an undefined value.

In addition to that, you shouldn't be using `on()` for queries in Cloud Functions.  You should only use `once()` to fetch a value a single time.  Your first query is using `on()`, but the others are using `once()`.

Lastly, your function will be easier to read and write if you chain your queries using the promises returned by once() rather than nesting deeply with callbacks.